# Trying to compare all elements in a list in F#

Tags: f#, match

So what I am trying to do is write a function that recursively checks if two ships hit each other. I have a solution but it doesn't do at all what i want. The outcome should be a list of all ships that collide with each other. so if x and y collide with each other the output list should be [x;y]

The code to build the ships is

```
type Ship =
{
Id : int
Name : string
X : int
Y : int
}
with
 static member Create ( id , name , x , y ) =
     {
     Id = id
     Name = name
     X = x
     Y = y
     }

let ships =
[
    Ship.Create(0 , " HMS Horizon " , 0 , 5)
    Ship.Create(1 , " Titanic " , 2 , 5)
    Ship.Create(2 , " The Iceberg " , 2 , 5)
    Ship.Create(3 , " USS Mississipi " , 0 , 5)
    Ship.Create(4 , " Battleship Yamato " , 3 , 5)
]
```

And here is my function I wrote to tackle the issue. But it doesn't work at all

```
let rec collisions(ships : List<Ship>) : List<Ship> =
 match ships with
 | [] -> []
 | [x] -> [x]
 | x :: y :: rest->
     if (x.X = y.X) && (x.Y = y.Y) then
         [x ; y] @ collisions (rest)
     elif (x.X <> y.X) || (x.Y <> y.Y) then
         [y] @ collisions (rest)
     else
         []
```

I think I need to compare all elements of ships with each other and make a new list of the ships that overlap coordinate wise. Although I don't know how I would go about doing this. Also, i'd like to keep the structure of the recursive function if at all possible.

Comment: If `x` collides with `y`, `y` collides with `z`, but `z` does not collide with `x`, what should the output be? Also: please clarify the statement "_doesn't work at all_". This is not a good description of a problem.

Comment: Sorry, but where do you see a z? Yes I realize now that the problem statement is pretty vague I did figure it out in the end. I'll the solution to my original post @FyodorSoikin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood right, all you need to do is to group by coordinates. You'll get a list of Ship list with all possible collisions:

```
let collisions (ships : Ship list) =
    ships |> List.groupBy (fun s -> s.X,s.Y) //group by coordinates
    |> List.filter (fun (_,s) -> List.length s > 1) //keeps only collisions
    |> List.map snd //drops coordinate ID created by groupBy
```